Correlation coefficient and coefficient of determination
I meet the concept: Correlation coefficient ($r$) and coefficient of determination ($r^2$). I also know that we can deduce $r$ from $r^2$.
$r^2$ helps us to find that whether the model fits well or not, and $r$ also shows this. I think they have the same function. So why we need $r$ then? or what is the meaning of its existence?

In contast to $r^2$ the correlation coefficient r shows the direction of the (linear) correlation of two data sets.
